# Как расширить глобальный класс?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Вопрос в следующем, хочу в Object добавить метод расширения `isUndefined`. Как это сделать?

Comment: но зачем? если можно просто использовать `===`?

Comment: Ради одного сравнения не стал бы, а вот когда 10 и более свойств сравнить надо в разных частях, то без такой функции просто никуда и никак.

Comment: но ведь это по прежнему оператор `===`

Comment: Безусловно. Но одно дело писать каждый раз писать сравнение или написать вызов функции. ``isDefined`` меньшее из зол, у меня в планах ещё ``IsNullOrUndefined`` и т.д.

Comment: _Но одно дело писать каждый раз писать сравнение или написать вызов функции._ - не вижу разницы, кроме дополнительного вызова функции.

Comment: Добавьте сюда ещё повышение читабельности кода, уменьшение объёма кода и т.д

Comment: читабельность спорно, но уж несколько `===` точно меньше нескольких вызовов `isDefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, пока писал, разобрался:

```
interface Object {
    isUndefined(value: any): boolean;
}

Object.prototype.isUndefined = function (): boolean {
     return this === undefined;
}
```

Размещаем в `*.ts.` файле. Лично у меня все файлы классов лежат в папке `models/classes`, а файлы интерфейсов в `models/interfaces`. Следовательно, файл интерфейса я поместил в `models/interfaces`. 
Далее, в папке `models` создан `index.ts` файл в котором подключены все объекты из подпапок (`classes`/`interfaces`). В этом файле пишем `import`

```
import './<путь до вашего файла>'
```

Дальше наступает счастье :)